# how to refer to the id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to delete row by calling rest web service using jquery. in the url field i have to mention the id dyanmically in jquery . this is my code

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee List</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id = "add">
        <h1>Add Employee</h1><br>
        <table>
        <tr><td>Id : </td><td><input type="text" id="empId" disabled="true" readonly = "true" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name : </td><td><input type="text" id="name" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Age : </td><td><input type="text" id="age" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Salary : </td><td><input type="text" id="salary" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Address : </td><td><input type="text" id="address" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type = "submit" value = "submit" ></td></tr>
        </table></form>
        <form id=  "list">
        <h1>Employee List</h1>
        <table  id= "content" border= "0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id = "emp">
        </tbody>    
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        listEmployee();
        addEmployee();
        deleteEmployee();
    });

    function listEmployee(){

        $.ajax({

            url: '/Ram/rest/restemployees',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){

                $.each(data, function(i,value){
                    $("#content tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + value.id + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.name + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.age + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.salary + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.address + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + "<button onClick='deleteEmployee()'>Edit</button" + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + "<button id='btnDel'>Delete</button>" +"</tr>")
                });

            },
            error: function(data){

            }

        });
    }

    function addEmployee(){

        $("#add").submit(function(e){

            var employee  = new Object();
            employee.name = $("#name").val();
            employee.age = $("#age").val();
            employee.salary = $("#salary").val();
            employee.address = $("#address").val();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({

                url : "/Ram/rest/add",
                type : "POST",
                data : employee,
                success : function(data){
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                error : function(data){

                }

            });
        });

    }

    function deleteEmployee(){

        var employee = new Object();
        employee.id = $("#empId").val();
        var id = $("#empId").val();
            $.ajax({

                url : "/Ram/rest/delete/" + id  ,
                type : "GET",
                data: employee,
                success: function(data){
                    alert("2");
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                error : function(data){

                }
            });

    }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

but the url is not accepting id value. how can i pass the url value dynamically?

Comment: what you mean by `but the url is not accepting id value`? What is exactly happening? `"/Ram/rest/delete/" + id` looks correct.

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/Ram/rest/delete/[object%20HTMLInputElement]?id= 400 (Bad Request).   I got this error

Comment: could you please share relevant HTML which has element with an id  `empId`?

Comment: i guess the problem is with `data`

Comment: its because you have two params here id and Employee which i believe is a model object why dont you just pass the id within that ie data:id=id,modalName=employee

Comment: data: employee what is the data in employee and why you are passing Id and Model differently.

Comment: <tr><td>Id : </td><td><input type="text" id="empId" disabled="true" readonly = "true" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove **Data** and then try it will work check below code : 
And URL is not correct URL should be : **"url : "/Ram/rest/delete?id=" + id  ,"**

```js
function deleteEmployee(){

        //var employee = new Object();

        var id = $("#empId").val();
            $.ajax({

                url : "/Ram/rest/delete?id=" + id  ,
                type : "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                data: 'json',
                cache: false,
                //data: employee,
                success: function(data){
                    alert("2");
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                error : function(data){

                }
            });

    }
```

**Second Possible way :**

```js
var employee = {
            "id": $("#empId").val()
        }

        $.ajax({

            url: "/Ram/rest/delete/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            data: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json;",
            data: JSON.stringify(employee),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("2");
                location.reload(true);
            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: check with data: 'json', I have updated my code and also try with type:'Post' insted of GET

Comment: Share your 'delete' controller method

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}" , method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE  )
 public ResponseEntity<Employee> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id){
  
   employeeService.deleteEmployee(id);
   return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.OK);
 }

Comment: @PathVariable("id")  remove this in your method and then try to hit again

Comment: I have added second way you check updated ans : Please check this URL in your browser first only change the '101' to your real id http://localhost:8080/Ram/rest/delete/?id=101

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/Ram/rest/delete/?{%22id%22:%22%22}&_=1496907006760 400 (Bad Request) got this error

Comment: 149690700‌​6760 is your id ?

Comment: if yes then try to hit this url, run your applicaation before testing this URL localhost:8080/Ram/rest/delete?id=149690700‌​6760

Comment: the use your real id and the hit that URL